# C# Multithreading Model

Tags: c#, multithreading, design-patterns

I've a c# single threaded application and currently working on to make it multi-threaded with the use of thread pools. I am stuck in deciding which model would work for my problem.

Here's my current scenario

```
While(1)
{
    do_sometask();
    wait(time);
}
```

And this is repeated almost forever. The new scenario has multiple threads which does the above. I could easily implement it by spawning number of threads based on the tasks I have to perform, where all the threads perform some task and wait forever.

The issue here is I may not know the number of tasks, so I can't just blindly spawn 500 threads. I thought about using threadpool, but because almost every thread loops forever and won't ever be freed up for new tasks in the queue, am not sure which other model to use.

I am looking for an idea or solution where I could break the loop in the thread and free it up instead of waiting, but come back and resume the same task after the wait(when the time gets elapsed, using something like a timer/checking timestamp of when the last task is performed).

With this I could use a limited number of threads (like in a thread pool) and serve the tasks which are coming in during the time old threads waits(virtually).

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Don't use explicit threads with a while loop and a sleep for this, use Timers instead and just have the next interval of the timer be the time you would have slept. Depending on [which timer you choose](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx) some use threads to run the "elapsed" event and others will run on the UI thread (you will likely want `System.Timers.Timer`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could implement it with the help of a threadpool and few conditions to check the last activity of the task before adding it to the threadpool queue.

Answer (score 2):

If all you have is a bunch of things that happen periodically, it sounds what you want is a bunch of timers. Create a timer for each task, to fire when appropriate. So if you have two different tasks:

```
using System.Threading;

// Task1 happens once per minute
Timer task1Timer = new Timer(
    s => DoTask1(),
    null,
    TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
    TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));

// Task2 happens once every 47 seconds
Timer task2Timer = new Timer(
    s => DoTask2(),
    null,
    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(47),
    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(47);
```

The timer is a pretty lightweight object, so having a whole bunch of them isn't really a problem. The timer only takes CPU resources when it fires. The callback method will be executed on a pool thread.

There is one potential problem. If you have a whole lot of timers all with the same period, then the callbacks will all be called at the same time. The threadpool *should* handle that gracefully by limiting the number of concurrent tasks, but I can't say for sure. But if your wait times are staggered, this is going to work well.

If you have small wait times (less than a second), then you probably need a different technique. I'll detail that if required.

Comment: thank you and @Scott Chamberlain I understand that timer would be helpful in terms of resource usage or avoiding the sleep/wait. Say I've a chat app where each thread is dedicated to a member where it checks for the updates,responds & wait for few secs and repeat the task. Effectively what I'd like to achieve is to have 'n' threads to handle 'm' members. In most cases members will be more than threads. And that's the reason I thought about somehow using a threadpool + some logic or similar model to utilize the wait time to come out and serve the new members. Hope I explained it better.

Comment: @Questions: For a chat application, you don't want to be maintaining threads at that level. In fact, you probably don't want to be polling. Search StackOverflow and Google for C# chat server. There are many examples. You probably want to use WCF for that.

Comment: I just used chat app as an example. My main problem is to avoid the number of threads and at the same time don't want to end up doing the task again before the actual time (wait) elapses. If I use a simple threadpool, I'd be able to perform tasks without any wait/loop. But I am looking for a logic/model on how & when to call the threads rather than calling the threads itself. i.e when task 1 is finished and out of the thread, it should be called again only after the wait time is over.

Comment: One thing you need to be careful with the `System.Theading.Timer`, If you don't keep the reference to the timer it can be garbage collected while the timer is running. This will stop your timer. `System.Timers.Timer` does not have this issue.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: Whereas that's true, `System.Timers.Timer` has the disadvantage of squashing exceptions that occur in the tick event. It also has no way to pass user data to the timer (the `State` parameter to the `System.Threading.Timer` constructor). The two advantages of the `Timers.Timer` are that it uses an event rather than a callback, and it has the `SynchronizingObject` that you can use to execute the event on the UI thread. But in my opinion those advantages don't outweigh the disadvantages. Especially the exception squashing.

Comment: @JimMischel I'm still not sure if timers can be implemented by the way I think of. Say, I want to re-use 10 threads for 20 tasks. 10 tasks(each of them will wait for 15 seconds after the task is completed) will enter the thread and when it's completed, I can queue in the next 10 tasks. But the issue here is how do I trigger again the first 10 tasks to be started exactly after 15 seconds elapses.

Answer (score 2):

With this design, you only have one thread blocked at any time.

Have one thread (the master thread) waiting on a concurrent blocking collection, such as the [BlockingCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx).  This thread will be blocked by a call to `TryTake` until something is placed in the collection, or after a certain amount of time has passed via a timeout passed into the call (more on this later).

Once it is unblocked, it may have a unit of work to be processed.  It checks to see if there is one (i.e., the `TryTake` call didn't time out), then if there is capacity to perform this work, and if so, queues up a thread (pool, Task or whatevs) to service the work.  This master thread then goes back to the blocking collection and tries to take another unit of work.  The cycle continues.

As a unit of work is begun, it will be noted so that the main thread can see how many threads are working.  Once this unit is completed, the notation will be removed.  The thread is then freed.

You want to use a timeout so that if it is judged that too many operations are running concurrently, you will be able to re-evaluate this a set period of time down the road.  Otherwise, that unit of work sits in the blocking collection until a new unit is added, which is not optimal.

Outside users of this instance can queue up new units of work by simply dropping them in the collection.

You can use a cancellation token to immediately unblock the thread when it's time to shut down operations.  Have the worker operations take cancellation tokens as well so they can halt on shutdown.